# AFNetworking SSL certificate fail iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, afnetworking-2

I spent a lot of time searching for answer but still no luck, so I decided to give up and ask for community help:

1 I have a dev server with self-signed cert

2 Yes I did used `policy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;`

3 SSL is on custom port 44302

4 I need to run a download task cause request returns a data stream

Here is my code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
policy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
manager.securityPolicy = policy;

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://self_signed_cert.net:44302/storage/%@/action.download", _ticketId]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Here is the error:

> 2015-08-03 18:18:15.901 SSL_TEST[1517:23943] Error: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a
>   secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo=0x787d2f20
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
>   connection to the server cannot be made.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://self_signed_cert.net:44302/storage/a430f316cfe076e9850874c0edad3dcb/action.download,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSUnderlyingError=0x787da700 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error
>   -1200.)", NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://self_signed_cert.net:44302/storage/a430f316cfe076e9850874c0edad3dcb/action.download}

will be appreciate for your help! Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm experiencing the same...

Comment: We moved upload and download to http, it still not works, sry

Answer (score 0):

I've tried on an empty project, it works on the App :

```
NSURL* lBaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myDomain/"];
    AFHTTPSessionManager* lSessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:lBaseURL
                                              sessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];


    AFSecurityPolicy* lPolicy= [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
    lPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

    lSessionManager.securityPolicy = lPolicy;


    [lSessionManager GET:@"https://myDomain/api/"
              parameters:nil
                 success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull JSON)
     {
         NSLog(@"success %@", JSON);
     }
                 failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, NSError * _Nonnull error)
     {
         NSLog(@"failure %@", error);
     }];
```

- Don't forget to add to your target (in the App AND in the watch App) your **.cer** file
- Activate ATS into the **.plist** `NSAppTransportSecurity`

But I'm stuck with the watchOS 2.0 extension. It just fail with this error :

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred
>   and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to
>   the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myDomain/api,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myDomain/api,
>   NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
>   connection to the server cannot be made.}

Comment: Maybe you should add the .cer file to your extension also?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did.